# How to fix Hibernation

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, thinkpad

I have an IBM thinkpad t42. I ran the hibernation command `sudo pm-hibernate` but when I startup my computer, I see the windows I had open before but I don't see the mouse and can't do anything or I see the mouse can move it around but can't do anything.  It shows me the last session I had open but am not able to do anything with it. I have tried installing `uswsusp` and running the command `s2disk` but it did the same thing.

Comment: That question is a different problem. I don't go to the login screen It goes to my session but I can't do anything with the session.  i tried the answer but it didn't fix my problem.  Should I try `Tux on Ice`? http://tuxonice.net/

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone's gotten Tux On Ice to work with Ubuntu ...but sure! It's worth a try. If you get it to work, then by all means please [post an answer about it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). This looked very similar so it got several close votes; if this *does* end up being incorrectly closed, please let us know and it can be reopened. (In the mean time I recommend *editing* your quesiton itself so that it explicitly explains the difference and that you tried the solutions presented in that other question. Thanks!)